# Will coldfusion correctly use sessions with AJAX?

Tags: session, cookies, coldfusion

If I'm doing an AJAX call from a coldfusion page (to another coldfusion page), will coldfusion correctly use sessions? I can't use cookies this way, right? The two pages would have separate application.cfc/cfm pages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Different applications (appliaction.cfc/cfm) have different session management.  Therefore, even if your ajax request carries the cfid/cftoken in the cookie, which it will, the destination cf application would not be able to access the session on the origin cf app.

Comment: This is what I was thinking would be the case. Very well stated.

Comment: Unless the different Application.cfm/.cfc files use the same application name. Then the session would be accessible from both.

Answer (score 2):

When your browser makes an HTTP request to a server, it will send all cookies for that domain in the headers regardless of whether it is a "normal" request or an Ajax request.  The user will have whatever session on the target site that they would normally have if they were hitting a page from that site by typing its URL in the address bar.